# @Scripts.Render not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I've registered bundle in BundleConfig like this:
 `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryupload").Include(
             "~/Scripts/jquery.upload-1.0.2.min.js"));`

And want to render it on the view like this:
 `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryupload")`

But my sript is not included in the page. 
Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do not include minified versions in your bundles:

```
ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryupload").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.upload-1.0.2.js"))
```

The whole point of the bundles is that they will take care of minifying and combining your static resources. You shouldn't register a `.min.js` in your bundles.

Comment: Can you post the example of registering .min.js files in the bundles?

Comment: Where is the best place to register .min files in bundles.What is the best approach?

Comment: As I already explained in my answer you should not be attempting to register such minified scripts with your bundles. Just include them as normal `<script>` includes. Or get a non-minified version that you could register with your bundles.

Comment: I think, possibly, what the OP was getting at in the follow up comment/question was how do you get the @Scripts.Render to render the minified version of the scripts. In which case the answer is that in release builds it will use file name conventions to find the min version. Or you can use `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` when configuring the bundles. If there is no minified version found then it will minify the file for you.

Comment: i used ScriptBundle for bundling CSS and got [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/glow-users/pDf8CzVa-Jc) error , **Be sure** to use `ScriptBundle` for Scripts and `StyleBundle` for CSS